# System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException?

Tags: wcf

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: 'An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost/Webservice/skynetservice.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.'

An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost/Webservice/skynetservice.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Posting just the error message is insufficient.  You need to explain what you're doing and with what code.

Comment: Hi Ewong, I am trying to run the Desktop Application and Web service on my local machine

Comment: Do you have a firewall blocking the webservice?

Comment: Hi Ewong, How can I check this?

Comment: Under Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Windows Firewall..  and this depends on what Windows you're using.

Comment: Maybe you can use the [service trace viewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/service-trace-viewer-tool-svctraceviewer-exe?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to try to find the real problem.